# Grooming a cowlick

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

Using hair geometry nodes, I'm having a problem grooming a cowlick like the ones on horses. When I tried to groom four guide curves in different directions, the interpolated hairs don't follow them at all. What do I do?

[image]

[image: Guide curves]
[image: Cowlick]
[image: Cowlick2]

Comment: Can you provide the blend file? Coz I had no issues

Comment: @Akshay2005 I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Either use https://blend-exchange.com/ or if larger than 30MB just upload it to your drive and share the link.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=j2Q557GB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/j2Q557GB/)

Comment: I could not really understand the reason completely and so I won't be able to give you an answer. But if you just want to fix this, then for now just change the interpolation guides amount to 3 instead of the current 4.

Comment: Even with three interpolation guides, the interpolated hairs are still off.

Comment: Uh, I mean the amount in the modifier not the guides that you created.